# Dynamic layout like google

Tags: layout, css-float

I am looking of a good example for dynamic 3 columns layout like this one from Google Search. I have see, that if the layout fits to every browser resulution. That menas, there is never a scroller if the resulution is 800, 1024 or >1024 . What kind of solution, can I use to become such effect? I have see, that the center content is floating, but how is it possible to fit for every resolution and is there a minimum of the width of the center, because if the browser goes smaller and smaller, there is a point, where the scroller is coming.

It will be great if anyone can redirects me to an similar example, please! I am interested in centered design, not left oriented like Google!

Comment: I found this good article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/gg619395 and this library http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/mediaqueries/ . I think here is the solution! Has anyone used this?

Comment: Here some cool designs: http://mediaqueri.es/

Comment: I found this very cool live example too: http://maxdesign.com.au/jobs/resolution/ But how is possible to fix the stuff for IE?

Comment: Can anyone test please this example maxdesign.com.au/jobs/resolution with IE6 and IE7 and IE9 and tell me if it works? I have tested it with IEtester under Windows, but If there is someone with real browser it will be great to tell me, that this works fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one CSS feature.. 
Here it is [Google HTML5 site](http://www.html5rocks.com), where included this feature... Just try to change width of browser and scrollbar will not appear.. because css file has styles like

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 800px) { /* styles */ }
```

i.e. for some resolution you have some other styles..

take a look [they css](http://www.html5rocks.com/static/css/base.css)

Comment: But how are you discover the resolutions, when this is only possible with JS? I mean the CSS is static one, or if its dynamic, what is your default value? By my resolution the min-width is 1219. How they do this?

Comment: No it could be static.. just you should understand, that if user have resolution of his screen 800x600 then he has one style, if resolution is more than 800x600 and less than 1024x768 - he has another style for document... in example above defined styles for iPad resolution.

Comment: Hi Maxim, what about IE? Are there some solutions for this for IE7/8 .

Comment: Hi Niko Nik. 
Do you have any issues with this in IE 7/8 ?

Comment: Well I want to know if the IE 7 and IE6 supports this stuff and if there is some solution to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the CSS float tutorial, which I refer to every time I want to do a multicolumn. http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/